# Copying a MongoDB collection using pymongo and pasting it into another collection

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb

I want to copy a `coll` collection to make a backup in a database in MongoDB. So I tried:

```
>>> client = pymongo.MongoClient(
...             f"mongodb+srv://{user}:{password}@cluster0.n2hnd.mongodb.net/es_eso_importante?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
>>>
>>> db = client['test']
>>> source = db['coll']
>>> destination = db['coll_backup']
>>> pipeline = [ {"$match": {}},
...              {"$out": "coll_backup"}]
>>> db.coll.aggregate(pipeline)
<pymongo.command_cursor.CommandCursor object at 0x00000214564785F8>
```

But I don't have any changes on MongoDB Atlas.

If there are any other (free) alternatives I'm ready to hear them.

Comment: I just tried your code and it worked, so can't help.

Comment: @BellyBuster Yeah, the following day the documents were presents. I just retried to copy another one with another destination and it's still empty. Do you know long it takes?

Comment: It copies it straight away. Maybe you are looking in the wrong place?